# Excel: Looking for a VBA Solution to automate subtracting and adding to counts on separate page

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a document which is used for supply inventory for issued kit.

I have MS Excel document where it presently shows tabs for:
headware, miscellaneous, parkas, shirts, DEU tunics, FTU tunics, DEU pants, FTU pants, DEU boots, FTU boots

[image]

On each tab, the headers are: Type (what type of category), inventory ID (its a number), Name (title of the object for ordering), description (description of item), unit price, quantity in stock, reorder level, and quantity to reorder.

When I update this sheet, I want to scream. There is too many items (498 to be exact) and simply removing an item from each section as required, is extremely time consuming.

I was thinking of making the sheet have another tab where I insert the persons items issued and it auto removes it. But I have no idea how to do so. I would also need another tab for inbound items returned to me.

Help a girl out!

There are currently the following sections I would need searched, each dependant on the tabs.

[image]

Essentially,

I need the spreadsheet to search within each "name of item", then search the "size", and remove or add dependant on the sheet, the count in "quantity in stock".

Comment: The arrangement of your data makes it much more difficult to do what you want - ideally you'd have a single sheet listing all the inventory, with no "header rows" except for the very top of the table.  ie. add specific columns for "Name" and "size", and one for the information which is currently in the separate tab names.

Comment: Aside from the layout of your data, their quality does not lend themselves to automation, e.g. the 39 belts aren't of 'unknowable' size - someone just needs to use a tape measure. Once such misclassifications were eliminated I'd suggest creating a mapping table so that, e.g. 'Grey Socks' maps to 'Socks, Temperate, CF Charcoal Grey' maps to `Misc.` worksheet. Also, since your first screenshot seems to be from a mobile device, a VBA solution would not work there.